# Notations for Gamma distribution

Tags: math-mode, scientific-notation

Searching on here, seems like the appropriate notation for Normal distribution is `\mathcal{N}`, which looks like:
[image: Normal distribution]

However, if I use `\mathcal{Ga}` for Gamma distribution, it looks like this:
[image: Gamma notations]
which is clearly wrong. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) uses `\Gamma`. However, I'm using the Gamma function elsewhere in my paper so I want the Gamma distribution to use a different symbol. Any recommendations here?

Comment: Why not just `$\mathcal{G}$`? I guess that the a is not in the calligraphic font you use.

Comment: Many math-script and math-caligraphic fonts don't provide glyphs for lowercase letters. As a result, the output of `$\mathcal{a}$` is not specified for these fonts.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I guess I can simply use `$\mathcal{G}$`. It's just that I've seen `\Gamma(a, b)`, `Ga(a, b)` and `Gam(a, b)` in terms of notations, but not `G(a, b)`.